# Getting unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, jenkins

I am getting below exception while running the console application:
I am facing a build issue (in release mode) and on Jenkins server which is running on a remote machine.
I am dealing with command line arguments and I thnk the error cause means that when exe is run no arguments are passed.

```
    unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at VstoManifestGenerator.Program.WriteOutput(String entry, Object[] args) in C:\Dev\Client\VstoManifestGenerator\VstoManifestGenerator\Program.cs:line 318
   at VstoManifestGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Dev\Client\VstoManifestGenerator\VstoManifestGenerator\Program.cs:line 164
```

**Below is my command line argument:**

```
C:\Dev\Client\AddIns\Office\Word2010AddIn\bin\XTS.Office.AddIn.Word.dll Debug amd64
```

I don't have this issue on the local dev machine in debug configuration, I didn't figure out what causing this issue.

Can anyone here help me to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: This is about the time you should know about [mcve]

Comment: You set `_ouputfile` _after_ first (potential) call to `WriteOutput`. (In Main)

Comment: ^^ And you are calling `WriteOutput` in the `catch` (the outer one in Main), where it is possible that `_ouputfile` has not been set, yet. Which I guess is line 164 from Stacktrace?

Comment: It would help if you told us what line the exception is occurring.  Step through code with F11 and set break points with F9.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace hints that `_outputfile` has not yet been set, when `WriteOutput` is called.

Make sure you initialize it *before* any call to `WriteOutput` is made.

Mind:

```
string dependency;

try{

    // exception thrown HERE

    dependency = "somepath"; // <= Will not be executed
}
catch
{
    CallToMethodDependingOnDependency(); // <= Will throw again
}
```

At first glance this *looks* like the call is after dependency is set but the exception jumps the initialization.

Comment: I did as you said.I found that when "Mage(string.Format(@"-Update ""{0}"" -Version {1} -FromDirectory ""{2}""", tempManifest, version,finfo.Directory.FullName));"
is called.

Comment: the result string variable is containing below string value
 "Internal error, please try again. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013101B). and this string value is passed as parameter of WriteOutput() method

Comment: Also , when I am running the same application in release cofiguration then it is throwing the exception of "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"

Comment: what is causing this issue ?

Comment: These are different issues. The first you mentioned seems to be an older version of the dotnet framework installed on the target machine than the version you target your application to. The latter one ... no idea. But that would be another question, too.

Comment: But then again: the array is the result of a `Split`. You should always check if the split results in as many array items as expected. For example you can check simply `if ( r.length < 3 ) // do some error handling`

Comment: Also, for debugging purposes, I'd recommend a logging framework.

Comment: You probably forgot to put a try catch block around your call.   You may be throwing an exception but it is not handled by the catch block.